# ImportError: No module named src.utils tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load tensorflow within jupyter notebook and receive the following error:

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-28a19874e1dd> in <module>()
      5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
----> 7 from tf_utils import load_dataset, random_mini_batches, convert_to_one_hot, predict
      8 
      9 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')

/Pathway/tf_utils.py in <module>()
     17 import sys
     18 import tensorflow as tf
---> 19 import src.utils as utils
     20 import logging
     21 from tensorflow.contrib import slim

ImportError: No module named src.utils
```

---

I have the latest tensorflow installed and have also added models to the PYTHONPATH via:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/Pathway/tfmodels-1.9.0"
```

Do you know how I can resolve this import error?

Comment: What is `tf_utils`? Did you pip install that?

Comment: Yes I have installed tf_utils from 
   https://github.com/neuroailab/tfutils via [pip install git+https://github.com/neuroailab/tfutils.git]

Comment: Hmm, are you very new to Python? Maybe you are looking instead for this file, which defines the functions you are attempting to import? https://github.com/andersy005/deep-learning-specialization-coursera/blob/master/02-Improving-Deep-Neural-Networks/week3/Programming-Assignments/tf_utils.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this import error I manually imported the missing functions from the following github repo > https://github.com/andersy005/deep-learning-specialization-coursera/blob/master/02-Improving-Deep-Neural-Networks/week3/Programming-Assignments/tf_utils.py